# WM_ACTIVATEAPP Message handle is NOT the handle of the window being activated

Tags: .net, winapi, hook

I have more than one desktop application for which I have the root window handles. I set up hooking so that I can watch for messages for these windows.

For example I set up my hooking to look for the message WM_ACTIVATEAPP to know if one of my watched applications is activated.

But when I look at the handle coming with the message, it isn't the window handle, it is some other handle, which is not part of the application's "tree" of windows.  See this from Spy++:

[image: SPY++ SCREEN GRAB]

I had assumed that the message handle would match my application window handle being hooked, but this is not the case.

My question is how to determine which window/application is being activated from the handle passed in the message and knowledge of windows and associated processes?

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand what you mean by "message handle." However, according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-activateapp) the `WM_ACTIVATEAPP` doesn't include a ***window*** handle in its parameters ... just a flag indication activation or inactivation and a **thread identifier**.

Comment: Ok, so how do I get from the thread handle to the parent application of that thread?

Comment: From a VB forum: *You would have to enumerate all top level windows and then GetWindowThreadProcessId on each one to see which ones match your PID.* [link](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?435704-how-to-find-window-handle-using-process-ID-or-thread-ID) But also remember the `WM_ACTVATEAPP` is sent by/to both the activating and the deactivating applications.

Comment: [WM_ACTIVATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-activate) passes the window handle being activated/deactivated along.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for their comments.

It appears I can simply do a GetForegroundWindow() to return the handle to the newly activated window.

Using WM_ACTIVATEAPP, it looks like the thread identifier in the message eventually leads to back to my application doing the hooking and not the application being activated. So this was a dead end.

This also seems to apply to WM_ACTIVATE. However, this may be do to my setting my application window as a child window of the application. Not fully sure about that one.